# Google Sheets: How to display 0 when reference cell is 0 and blank when reference cell is empty?

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to set up a Google Sheet cell that returns a 0 if the sum of the reference cells are 0 OR shows as blank when the reference cells are empty.  I seem to be able to do one or the other.

Formula:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SUM(D3,E3))=0,0,(IFERROR(SUM(D3,E3))))
```

returns 0 when reference cells sum = 0 (correct) but when reference cells are empty still shows 0 (incorrect, I want it blank in this case).

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but can't seem to wrap my head around it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more succinct approach:

```
=arrayformula(if(and(isblank({D3,E3})),,sum(D3,E3)))
```

Comment: Works flawlessly - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(result,iferror(sum(D3,E3)),
     ifs(counta(D3,E3)=0,,result=0,0,1,result))
```